# Как принято организовывать подтягивание отзывов о товарах с Яндекс Маркета?

Tags: архитектура

В процессе исследования я натыкался на сервисы, типа cackle и аналоги (готовые виджеты), apisystem (апишка для запросов спарсенных отзывов), ну и на саму API Яндекса.

Каталог товаров у нас не маленький (38к позиций).

В моём понимании самый правильный способ - это проплатить апи яндекса, спарсить отзывы к себе куда-нибудь, организовать сервис для отдачи отзывов. Когда будет выполнена основная работа, можно не проплачивать сервис, а пользоваться бесплатными 100 запросами в сутки для обновления старых отзывов.

Подскажите, верно ли я мыслю? Или что-то я упускаю из виду.

Comment: Верно, одобряем

Comment: У вас есть способ узнать, для каких товаров у вас старые отзывы? Иначе если будете перебирать весь каталог, то для его обновления вам понадобится 38000 / 100 = 380 суток.

Comment: @andreycha, да, мы на этапе проектирования. Планируем обновлять в сутки по 50 устаревших популярных и 50 просто самых старых (по этим сущностям могу выборку сделать без проблем).

Comment: Т.е. вы опираетесь на критерий "у товара отзывы старее Х дней", но на самом деле не знаете, появились ли новые отзывы на Маркете, пока не сделаете запрос?

Comment: @andreycha, я понимаю Ваш вопрос, но разве можно узнать - появились ли новые отзывы - не делая запроса? Кажется, по-любому придется делать запрос.

Comment: С Яндекс.Маркетом я не работал, поэтому деталей не знаю. Хочу лишь указать, что при таком подходе у вас в любой момент времени будут товары, в которых отзывы не обновлялись больше года. Вас это устраивает?

Comment: @andreycha, Ваши советы очень ценны для нас, спасибо! Мы будем думать, как решить эту ситуацию и как сбалансировать всё более ли менее. Возможно, мы составим индекс высокомаржинальных товаров для нас и будем и приоритете обновлять их, а на низкомаржинальные отзывы будут не всегда актуальны. Либо будем раз в 2-3 месяца проплачивать запросы к Яндексу и парсить заново все товары. Спасибо, что помогаете увидеть возможные проблемы. :)